# Parent/child relationships: adding/updating details to an answer

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Answer is the Parent table and AnswerDetail is the child.  Below works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this using EF?

**My Method Signature is this:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Evaluator(EvaluationVM evaluation, string command)
```

**It is coming from a MVC 4 application.**

```
Answer AnswerRecord;
AnswerRecord = (db.Answers).Where(x => x.TeacherID.Equals(evaluation.CurrentTeacher.ID)).Where(y => y.LeaderID != null).FirstOrDefault<Answer>();

if (AnswerRecord == null)
{
     //Add New Parent Record:
     AnswerRecord.CreatedBy = userName;
     AnswerRecord.CreateStamp = DateTime.Now;
     db.Entry(AnswerRecord).State = EntityState.Added;

     AnswerRecord.UpdatedBy = userName;
     AnswerRecord.UpdateStamp = DateTime.Now;
 }

 AnswerRecord.UpdatedBy = userName;
 AnswerRecord.UpdateStamp = DateTime.Now;

 //I use this block if I know the child record is new:
 adItem = db.AnswerDetails.Find(item.LeaderAnswerDetailKey);
  if (adItem != null)
  {
       adItem.Comment = item.LeaderComment;
       adItem.AnswerOptionKey = item.LeaderAnswerOptionKey.Value;
       adItem.UpdatedBy = userName;
       adItem.UpdateStamp = DateTime.Now;
       db.Entry(adItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
  }

 foreach (EvaluationObject item in evaluation.ResultSet)
 {
 //I use this block if I am updated the child record
 adItem = new AnswerDetail();
 adItem.QuestionID = item.QuestionID.Value;
 adItem.AnswerOptionKey = item.TeacherAnswerOptionKey.Value;
 adItem.Comment = item.TeacherComment;

 adItem.CreatedBy = userName;
 adItem.CreateStamp = DateTime.Now;
 adItem.UpdatedBy = userName;
 adItem.UpdateStamp = DateTime.Now;
 adItem.AnswerKey = AnswerRecord.AnswerKey;

 AnswerRecord.AnswerDetails.Add(adItem);
 db.Entry(adItem).State = EntityState.Added;

 //This is called at the end of my method:
 db.SaveChanges();

 }//End of ForEach Loop
```

**EvaluationVM**

```
public class EvaluationVM
{
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool IsLeader { get; set; }
    public int TeacherStatus { get; set; }
    public int LeaderStatus {get;set;}

    public bool IsPublicTeacher { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinalTeacher { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublicLeader { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinalLeader { get; set; }

    public List<EvaluationObject> ResultSet {get; set;}
    public TeacherInfo CurrentTeacher {get; set;}
    public LeaderInfo CurrentLeader { get; set; }

    public List<EvaluationRating> RatingSet {get;set;}
}
```

**EvaluationObject:**

```
    public class EvaluationObject : IEvaluationObject
    {
        public int? QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string IndicatorID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionDescription { get; set; }

        public string TeacherID { get; set; }
        public int? TeacherStatusKey { get; set; }
        public int? TeacherAnswerKey { get; set; }
        public int? TeacherAnswerDetailKey { get; set; }
        public int? TeacherAnswerOptionKey { get; set; }
        public string TeacherComment { get; set; }

        public string LeaderID { get; set; }
        public int? LeaderStatusKey { get; set; }
        public int? LeaderAnswerKey { get; set; }
        public int? LeaderAnswerDetailKey { get; set; }
        public int? LeaderAnswerOptionKey { get; set; }
        public string LeaderComment { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Are all code blocks in the same method? If so, it would be nice if you could add the method's signature; if not, splitting the code block into distinct methods would make it easier to review.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - The Method is a controller from a MVC application.  So it is the form that got submitted.

Comment: Is there more to the method? I commented that, because right now it's not immediately apparent where `userName`, `evaluation` and `item` come from and what type they are - having the method's signature would help connect the dots ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I updated the question with more information.  Let me know if you need more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Separation of Concerns

I like that you're using EF's built-in unit-of-work implementation. However `db` (your `DbContext` class) looks like it's declared at instance level in your controller - make sure it's disposed properly at the end of the request (you could inject the context in the controller's constructor and use an IoC container to ensure per-request instantiation & disposal).

That doesn't mean the controller's `[HttpPost]` methods should be doing all the work!

Looking at the method's code, I think you can extract an entire *service class* that exposes at least 3 methods!

- `Answer CreateNewAnswer(string userName)`
- `AnswerDetail FindByLeaderId(int leaderId)`
- `AnswerDetail CreateNewAnswerDetail(int answerId, AnswerDetailVM item)`

Extracting these methods into their own class will make it much easier to follow your controller methods' code, by adding a *level of abstraction* - the controller shouldn't be dealing with minute details, rather should call into more specialized objects that do their specialized stuff. Shortly put, *separate the concerns* ;)

---

#### SaveChanges

You don't need to call `db.SaveChanges()` for every entity you create in the loop - EF's `DbContext` is a *unit-of-work* that encapsulates a transaction, so calling `SaveChanges` is like saying *"I'm done, now commit all these pending changes!"* - call it once (or, as sparingly as possible - e.g. the *parent* would typically needs to exist in the db before a *child* can be added), when you're done.

---

#### Naming & Other Nitpicks

> ```
> Answer AnswerRecord;
> AnswerRecord = (db.Answers).Where(x => x.TeacherID.Equals(evaluation.CurrentTeacher.ID)).Where(y => y.LeaderID != null).FirstOrDefault<Answer>();
> ```

For readability, I prefer to split these across multiple lines:

```
AnswerRecord = (db.Answers).Where(x => x.TeacherID.Equals(evaluation.CurrentTeacher.ID))
                           .Where(y => y.LeaderID != null)
                           .FirstOrDefault<Answer>();
```

This is confusing, because `x` and `y` refer to the same object. Also I'd prefer `==` over `.Equals` in most cases, so I'd write it like this instead:

```
var answer = db.Answers.Where(answer => answer.TeacherID == evaluation.CurrentTeacher.ID
                                     && answer.LeaderID != null)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

The type parameter for `FirstOrDefault` is inferred from usage, doesn't need to be specified ;)

---

#### Comments

If these comments are real, in-code comments...

> ```
> //I use this block if I know the child record is new:
> ```

> ```
> //I use this block if I am updated the child record
> ```

...then they're both lying - the code blocks under each comment seems to be doing what the other comment is saying! Remove these misleading comments, calling `_service.CreateNewAnswerDetail` should be clear enough that you're creating a new `AnswerDetail` entry ;)

As for this one:

> ```
> //Add New Parent Record:
> ```

and this one:

> ```
> //End of ForEach Loop
> ```

...they both say nothing that the code doesn't say already, remove them as well, thank yourself later ;)

Comment: With the db.Save() the way it currently is (inside the for loop), I have a similar method that does the same thing except it does deletes (finds a record then deletes it) and the inserts new records.  Like I said the db.save() is currently inside the foreach loop like I have above.  Would that possibly cause a deadlock on the table?  Let me know if you need further info?

Comment: You cannot garantee the order of operations in `db.Save`, so if you need to first delete records, delete them, `Save()`, and then add the new ones. It would probably be best to *update* than *delete+insert* though.